# Should I use Thévenin to calculate emitter current for current in common-collector amplifier?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, common-collector

Determine the total input resistance of the emitter-follower in the figure below. Also find the voltage gain, current gain, and power gain in terms of power delivered to the load, RL. Assume \$\beta_{ac} = 175 \$ and that the capacitive reactances are negligible at the frequency of operation.

[image]

This is the analysis from the textbook:

$$R_e = R_E \parallel R_L = 470 \ \mathrm{V} \parallel 470 \ \mathrm{V} = 235 \ \mathrm{\Omega}$$

$$R_{in(base)} \approx \beta_{ac} R_e = (175)(235\ \mathrm{V}) = 41.1\ \mathrm{k\Omega}$$

$$R_{in(tot)} = R1 \parallel R2 \parallel R_{in(base)} = 18 \ \mathrm{k\Omega} \parallel 51 \ \mathrm{k\Omega} \parallel 41.1 \ \mathrm{k\Omega} = 10.1 \ \mathrm{k\Omega}$$

$$V_E = (\frac{R_2} {R_1 + R_2}) V_{cc} - 0.7 = \frac{51 \ \mathrm{k\Omega}} {18\ \mathrm{k\Omega} + 51\ \mathrm{k\Omega}} 10\ \mathrm{V} - 0.7\ \mathrm{V} = 6.69\ \mathrm{V}$$

$$I_E = \frac{V_E} {R_{E}} = \frac{6.69\ \mathrm{V}} {235\ \mathrm{\Omega}} = 14.2\ \mathrm{mA}$$

---

The following is my analysis:

[image]

$$R_{th} = R_1 \parallel R_2 = 18\ \mathrm{k\Omega} \parallel 51\ \mathrm{k\Omega} \approx 13.3\ \mathrm{k\Omega}$$
$$V_{th} = V_{cc} \frac{R_2} {R_1 + R_2} = 10 V \frac{51\ \mathrm{k\Omega}} {18\ \mathrm{k\Omega} + 51\ \mathrm{k\Omega}} \approx 7.39\ \mathrm{V}$$

$$ R_e = R_E \parallel R_L = 470\ \mathrm{\Omega} \parallel 470\ \mathrm{\Omega} = 235\ \mathrm{\Omega} $$

$$I_E = \frac{V_{th} - 0.7\ \mathrm{V}} {\cfrac{R_{th}} {\beta_{ac}} + R_E} = \frac{7.39\ \mathrm{V} - 0.7\ \mathrm{V}} {\cfrac{13.3\ \mathrm{k\Omega}} {175} + 470 \ \mathrm{\Omega}} \approx 12.2643\ \mathrm{mA}$$

$$r'_e = \frac{25\ \mathrm{mV}} {I_E} = \frac{25\ \mathrm{mV}} {12.2643\ \mathrm{mA}} \approx 2.0384\ \mathrm{\Omega}$$

$$
\begin{align}
R_{in(tot)} &= R1 \parallel R2 \parallel \beta_{ac} (r'_e + R_e) 
\\
&= 18\ \mathrm{k\Omega} \parallel 51\ \mathrm{k\Omega} \parallel (175 \times (2.0384 +235) \times 10^{-3}\ \mathrm{k\Omega}
\\
&\approx 10.087415\ \mathrm{k\Omega}
\end{align}$$

Comment: What answer do you expect to get from us?

Comment: @G36 Which analysis is more accurate? Mine or the Textbook's?

Comment: In that case, your analysis is more accurate than the book version.

Comment: @G36 Thank you for your feedback! BTW, could you check the total input resistance of the emitter-follower? Is my analysis for total input resistance correct?

Comment: Yep, sure. Rin will be around 10k. so your answer looks good.  But why 1.16 instead of 2?

Comment: @G36 It's a typo :)

Comment: Also if you like to be so super accurate do you know that resistance seen at the transistor base when we are looking into the base terminal is equal to  \$(\beta + 1) * ( r_e + R_E||R_L )\$

Comment: In the real world when we do some hand calculations such accuracy in calculations is not needed this is not a math lesson. Because all components will have some initial tolerance. So we don't know the exact values of the resistors we used. As for the transistor is even worse. The spread in the BJTs parameters is huge. We do not know the exact value of Vbe voltage, the beta value, and so on. And this is why accurate calculations are not needed and it is a waste of time that only gives us a false illusion of certainty and accuracy.

Comment: @G36 Why is Vbe voltage not known? Isn't that supposed to either 0.6 V or 0.7 V in DC?

Comment: The Vbe and the transistor current gain \$ \beta\$ are current (Ic) and temperature-dependent. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123705/what-does-25c-mean-on-a-transistor-data-sheet

Comment: @G36 Thank you for your link. I am wondering how Analog Chip designers take this temperature dependent constant into account. Their design have to absolutely correct  before tape-out because it takes huge amount of money to manufacture. Any hints?

Comment: On the IC. transistors will have much better thermal coupling than discrete transistors. Also, they will be better matched than the discrete version. And the circuit solution will use the current source and bandgap reference (low temp drift).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I get for variables ... (Simulated for checking).
If the capacitor's impedance is "negligible", read data where curves are "horizontal" (frequency high enough).

Output impedance is calculated as usual ( Vopen (load open) / Icc (load shorted).

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what `step data` mean?

Comment: The beta of BJT (beta is very variable) is stepped (from 163 to 652) for checking the dispersion of answers depending on that parameter. One can see that results are quasi "independent" of beta.

Comment: Is beta of BJT changing all the time in AC circuit?

Comment: No. Change with type of BJT, and "only" with the temperature.